# How to retrieve values from multiple rows as a single string

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I have made MySQL database with three columns `tags_id`,`tags`,`user_id`, it must give out all the tags with respect to the `user_id` given.

eg: for this link:"http://allwaysready.16mb.com/Cuboid/tagsTest.php?user_id[]=7"

Output is:

```
{"result":[{"tags":"Pascol"},{"tags":"PHP"},{"tags":"Python"}]}
```

But I need my result to be in a sing string like this:

```
{"result":[{"tags":"Pascol","PHP",","Python"}]}
```

It should not be in array i want it in a single string.

Here is my php code :

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET'){

    $user_id  = $_GET['user_id'];

    require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $user_tags = array();

    foreach ($_REQUEST['user_id'] as $key => $val) {
        $user_tags[$key] = filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
    $user_ids = "'" . implode("','", $user_tags) . "'";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user_tags WHERE user_id IN ({$user_ids})";

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    //creating a blank array 
    $result = array();

    //looping through all the records fetched
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

        //Pushing name and id in the blank array created 
        array_push($result,array(
           "tags"=>$row['tags']
        ));
    }

    //Displaying the array in json format 
    echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));

    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

what should i change in my code.?
please help me guys thank you.

Comment: Remove array_push and try this $result[tags][] = $row['tags'];

Comment: {"result":[{"tags":"Pascol","PHP",","Python"}]} ?  its not even a valid  `json` string, you mean {"result":[{"tags":"Pascol,PHP,Python"}]}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `array_push` mean

Push to your array new element with $key => $value

So solution in this case is remove `array_push` and try

```
$result['tags'][] = $row['tags'];
```

Comment: but after adding this code tags is considered to be an array . i want to be remain as string only .

Comment: Your result "tags":"Pascol","PHP",","Python" must use array do it. I'm sorry about late reply.